# Value error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python code that goes as:

```
...
bestProb=-1;
bestIndex=-1;
prob=np.zeros(numClasses) #numClasses=2
for i in range(0,numClasses):
   prob[i]=findProb(x,weights,b,i)
for i in range(0,numClasses):
   if prob[i]>bestProb:
       bestProb=prob
       bestIndex=i
...
```

The number of classes is 2. When I run this code, I get the error:

```
File "regression.py", line 19, in predict
if prob[i]>bestProb:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I understand that this error would occur if I compare my entire array with a single number, but ain't I using just one number when I write `prob[i]`? If I'm wrong, please tell me how can I fix it. Thanks!

Also, note that findProb() gives a number, and not a sequence. So that isn't any issue either.

**EDIT**: The problem was in `bestProb=prob`. It should've been `bestProb=prob[i]`. Sorry for the troubles. Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `type(prob[i])`?

Comment: @glhr <type 'numpy.float64'>

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your `Prob[i]` variable. Try to add a `print(Prob[i])` before your `if` statement to observe the content of `Prob[i]`. Sometimes, it is just an array of one element and you only need to make it `Prob[i][0]`. If that does not work, then you need to check your logic.

Comment: I did that. It gives output like `0.9999999902637232` for all `i`

Comment: I just tried writing `prob[i][0]` and it gives me `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

Comment: That means you are accessing your element correctly. Maybe you can round your variable and convert it to float.   `if round(float(prob[i]),3)>bestProb`

Comment: the problem was in `bestProb=prob`. I fixed it and reflected it in my ques. Thanks